# How to upload multiple photos on aws at once?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, graphql

I use `react-native` with `graphQL`.

Now I can upload one single photo on aws successfully.

But I want to upload `multiple` files `at once`.

If I run `loop` I can successfully upload multiple files on aws as below.

```
  const onValid = ({ caption }) => {
    const uploadPhotoArray = selectPhoto.map((sp, index) => {
      return new ReactNativeFile({
        uri: sp,
        name: `${index}.jpg`,
        type: "image/jpeg",
      });
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < uploadPhotoArray.length; i++) {
      uploadPhotoMutation({
        variables: {
          caption,
          file: uploadPhotoArray[i],
        },
      });
    }
  };
```

But the problem is, if I upload 2 images, then it creates **two** rows on `aws` and `backend`.

In order to make it one row (post) with 2 images, I make file column of backend as `Array`, not `string`.

However I think the problem is the `frontend`.

I wanted to make `uploadPhotoArray` as `array` like below.

```
Array [
  ReactNativeFile {
    "name": "0.jpg",
    "type": "image/jpeg",
    "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20220306_020216.jpg",
  },
  ReactNativeFile {
    "name": "1.jpg",
    "type": "image/jpeg",
    "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20220305_201130.jpg",
  },
]
```

then tried to run `uploadPhotoMutation` with this array.

```
  uploadPhotoMutation({
    variables: {
      caption,
      file: uploadPhotoArray,
    },
  });
```

Then it will pass `array` data to backend.

But it seems now working.

If I can't pass Array data to backend, which means that one by one is possible, then I need to make this incoming data to array on backend.

But that's also hard for me.

If you want to clarify my question, I can answer in real-item and chat is also possible.
Please give me any idea. :(

**backend code**

```
const fileUrl = fileArrayCheck
  ? await uploadFileToS3(file, loggedInUser.id, "uploads")
  : await uploadStringleFileToS3(file, loggedInUser.id, "uploads");


export const uploadStringleFileToS3 = async (file, userId, folderName) => {
  console.log(file);
  AWS.config.update({
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_KEY,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
    },
  });
  const { filename, createReadStream } = await file;
  const readStream = createReadStream();
  const objectName = `${folderName}/${userId}-${Date.now()}-${filename}`;
  const { Location } = await new AWS.S3()
    .upload({
      Bucket: "chungchunonuploads",
      Key: objectName,
      ACL: "public-read",
      Body: readStream,
    })
    .promise();
  return [Location];
};

export const uploadFileToS3 = async (filesToUpload, userId, folderName) => {
  const uploadPromises = await filesToUpload.map((file) => {
    uploadStringleFileToS3(file, userId, folderName);
  });
  return Promise.all(uploadPromises);
};
```

Comment: You don't appear to have included any code that actually uploads files or any (backend) code that interacts with S3.

Comment: @jarmod - I add it to my post